# Accelerate element-wise matrix multiplication with complex number in python/numpy

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

I have a piece of code to do some element-wise matrix multiplication with complex number. This part will be run like 1 million times during the calculation. According to the performance test, this part take about 35~40% of total elapsed time. Hope there is some suggestion that I can get a better performance. Thanks.

It theory, the BLAS based method can be used to improved the performance. But I have tried to run the code with different number of threads. It doesn't work. This part still took the same elapsed time.

The code looks like:

```py
(               const_a * np.conj(a) * b
                - const_b * np.conj(b) * b
                + const_c * np.conj(c) * c
                ... )
```

Comment: Is `np.conj(a) * b` really correct? Isn't it actually `np.conj(a) * a`? If so, and if `const_a`, `const_b`, and `const_c` are all real, you might be able to save half of the flops that results in zero imaginary part.

Comment: @norio Hi Norio, it is a very useful suggestion. Thank you so much!